# Well Definition of a Linear Map

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space of continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$, with norm $$\lVert f\rVert = \max_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert f(x) \rvert$$  Let $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by  $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 , \text{if }x \in [0,1/2) \\ 1 , \text{if } x\in [1/2 ,1] \end{cases}$$ Show that the linear map $$T: X \to X,\quad f \mapsto gf$$ is continuous, and find its norm.

I am having trouble understanding how this linear map $T$ is being defined.  We are taking a $f \in X$, that maps $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and we are multiplying it by this function $g$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $T$ is in fact not well-defined, since the product $gf$ need not be continuous.  For instance, if $f$ is the constant function with value $1$, then $gf=g$ is not continuous.  I'm guessing that the codomain of $T$ is intended to be not $X$ but a larger space, such as the space of *all* bounded functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with norm $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$.

Comment: Ah, you posted this immediately after I edited my question. Given this bigger space, how does this change the contradiction?

Comment: @ElSpiffy.  It disappears.

Comment: @ElSpiffy it still says "continuous" functions. What exactly did you edit?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma appears it was edited off, I had added that if f was the constant function, then this would only hold if g was continuous.

Comment: @ElSpiffy if the domain remains $X=C([0,1])$ and not $X=B([0,1])$, you do need $g$ to be continuous, indeed. For $B([0,1])$ this is well-defined and I think the norm will be $1$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to restrict $X$ by requiring $f\in X\implies f(1/2)=0$?